# Why did this person get the tenacious badge... and where's mine?

Tags: discussion, badges

I know this has been dragged out quite a few times but from what I understand to get the tenacious badge you need > 5 zero vote chosen answers and they must make up more than 20% of your total answers.

I was looking at the [SO badge page for tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious) I'm assuming this is ordered with the most recent people first.

Currently at the top of the list is the user [Andrew Bullock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28543/andrew-bullock). Andrew currently has 247 answers and only has 13 zero accepted answers. Which is only 5.2%.

[Currently I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139196/xiaohouzi79) have 26 answers and 6 zero vote accepted answers which is 23%.

Can someone explain to me why Andrew received the tenacious badge and if I can expect one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self accepts are excluded and you have 2 of those

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

See [waffles' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63273/why-did-this-person-get-the-tenacious-badge-and-wheres-mine/63277#63277) for why you haven't gotten one

As for why Andrew did, the badge only counts your accepted answers; your answers that haven't been accepted are immaterial. He has 52 accepted answers and 13 of them have 0 votes, which is 25% (I didn't check to see if any were CW or self-accepts, but apparently not many were).

The badge description in my opinion is wrong, I interpret it as 20% of your total answers, but oh well